# Inplace modification for subset of elements within original python list

Tags: python, mapping, list-comprehension

I see how list comprehensions are good at returning subsets of lists or even across the board remappings if no condition is set. However the filtering conditions will return values in a list that may be smaller than the filtered list. How can I take the positions of the returned values and change those elements conditionally?

Here's a simple example,

```
>>> v = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd']
>>> t = ['a', 'k']
```

How can I modify the elements of `v` in `t` to map to new a new value, say `'z'`, to yield something like

```
>>> v = ['z' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'z' , 'g' , 'z', 'd']
```

There's many questions on SO with people coming from Matlab looking to do the equivalent of logical indexing, but mainly just for the purposes of *selecting* elements and not *modifying* them inplace as I wish to do. I'd like to do the equivalent of logical indexing for the purposes of modifying filtered elements.

I just found out too that I cannot provide multiple indexes as well to a Python list. I'm using Python 3.

```
>>> v[ [1,3] ] = 'z'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
>>> v[ 1:3 ] = 'z'
>>> v
['a', 'z', 'd', 'f', 'k', 'g', 'a', 'd']
```

`filter` works to give me an iterable of the actual objects, but I can't figure out how to modify the elements they point to.

```
>>> v = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd']
>>> t = ['a', 'k']
>>> p = filter(lambda x: x in t, v)
>>>
>>> for elem in p :
...    print(elem)
...
a
k
a
>>>
>>> for elem in p :
...    p = 'z'
...
>>>
>>> for elem in p :
...    print(elem)
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of a MATLAB array in Python is a numpy array, not a list.  You can't do logical indexing on a list, but you can on a numpy array.  So for your sort of task, a numpy array would work well:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> v = np.array(['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd'])
>>>
>>> v[v == 'a'] = 'z'
>>> v[v == 'k'] = 'z'
>>> print(v)
['z' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'f' 'z' 'g' 'z' 'd']
```

This becomes complicated when you have a larger sequence.  In that case, you can use `np.in1d` , which returns `True` for any element of the first sequence that is present in the second, and `False` for any that isn't.  This can also be used for logical indexing:

```
>>> t = ['a', 'c', 'f', 'k']
>>> v[np.in1d(v, t)] = 'z'
>>> print(v)
['z' 'b' 'z' 'd' 'z' 'z' 'g' 'z' 'd']
```

It would be faster to use a set here (`t = {'a', 'c', 'f', 'k'}`) but I am trying to keep things close to your example.

This approach is roughly equivalent to:

```
>>> t = ['a', 'c', 'f', 'k']
>>> for ti in t:
...     v[v == ti] = 'z'
...
```

numpy arrays also support multiple indexes, although the sequence of indexes must be a numpy array itself.

As others have pointed out, you can do simple replacement with list comprehensions and membership testing.  However, you can also use a dict, which would probably be simpler, and in my opinion clearer:

```
>>> t = ['a', 'k']
>>> tdict = dict.fromkeys(t, 'z')
>>> v2 = [tdict.get(vi, vi) for vi in v]
>>> print(v2)
['z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'd']
```

The `dict.fromkeys` method creates a `dict` where the keys are the elements of `t` and the values are all `z`.  It is equivalent to `{ti: 'z' for ti in t}`.

`dict.get(x, y)` gets value of the dictionary corresponding to the key `y`, and if there is no such key it returns `x`.  What my code does is it goes through each element in the list.  If that element is in the `tdict`, it replaces that value by the corresponding value in `tdict`.  If not, it replaces the value with itself (that is, it does nothing).

This isn't that much simpler than the membership testing examples.  However, if you need more complex replacement with multiple targets and multiple replacements, the dict approach becomes *much* cleaner:

```
>>> repdict = {'a': 'z', 'k': 'z', 'i': 'y', 'd': 'y', 'b': 't'}
>>> v2 = [repdict.get(ti, ti) for ti in v]
>>> print(v2)
['z', 't', 'c', 'y', 'f', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'y']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to map values in `v` to a fixed value `z` if they also are in `t` and leave them unchanged otherwise:

```
>>> print list(map(lambda i: 'z' if i in t else i, v))
['z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'd']
```

Alternatively, you can still use comprehensions:

```
>>> v[:] = [i if not (i in t) else 'z' for i in v]
>>> print v
['z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'd']
```

Personally, I would find defining function more apparent especially if you are working with functions taking more than one parameters. Because it is very easy to "freeze" fixed parameters via [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> def f(value, lookup, mapping_value):
...     if value in lookup:
...         return mapping_value
...     return value
```

--

```
>>> from functools import partial

>>> v = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd']
>>> t = ['a', 'k']

>>> func = partial(f, lookup=t, mapping_value='z')
>>> v[:] = [func(i) for i in v]
>>> print v
['z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change any matching values v in t, the most efficient way would be to use make `t` a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) if the elements are hashable and just use `in`:

```
v = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd']
st = {'a', 'k'}

v[:] = ["z" if s in st else s for s in v]
```

Or combine it with a generator expression:

```
v[:] = ("z" if s in st else s for s in v)
```

Using  `v[:]` will modify the original object/list `v`.

If your were to use a for loop, you would use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to update the list using the index when you find an element in v that is also in out set:

```
v = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd']
st = {'a', 'k'}

for ind,ele in enumerate(v):
    if ele in st:
        v[ind] = "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
>>> v = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'f' , 'k' , 'g' , 'a', 'd']
>>> t = {'a', 'k'}
>>> new_v = [item if (item not in t) else 'z' for item in v]
>>> new_v
['z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'z', 'g', 'z', 'd']
>>>
```